# Error: ER_EMPTY_QUERY: Query was empty in node.js with mySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm working on a login form with node.js and MySQL as the database. When I run the program and try to register a new user I get this error when I press submit.

When I press submit I get the following error in the console in the inspect page in chrome: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9GJV.png) and I get in the terminal inside vs code the following error:

> node:internal/process/promises:288
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
> ^
> Error: ER_EMPTY_QUERY: Query was empty
> at Sequence._packetToError (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
> at Query.ErrorPacket (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
> at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
> at Parser._parsePacket (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
> at Parser.write (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
> at Protocol.write (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
> at Socket. (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
> at Socket. (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
> --------------------
> at Protocol._enqueue (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
> at Connection.query (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
> at register (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\controllers\register.js:9:12)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
> at Route.dispatch (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
> at Function.process_params (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
> at next (D:\programmeer stuff\javascript\informatica site\New folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10) {
> code: 'ER_EMPTY_QUERY',
> errno: 1065,
> sqlMessage: 'Query was empty',
> sqlState: '42000',
> index: 0,
> sql: undefined
> }

The code I try to run is:

`controllers/register.js`

```
const db = require("../routes/db-config");
const bcrypt =require("bcryptjs")

const register = async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password: Npassword} = req.body
    if(!email || !Npassword) return res.json({satus:'error', error:"Please enter your email and password"});
    else{
        console.log(email);
        db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?' [email], async(err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(result[0])return res.json({satus:'error', error:"email already in use"})
            else {
                const password = bcrypt.hash(Npassword, 8);
                console.log(password)
                db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {email: email, password: password}, (error, results)=>{
                    if (error) throw error;
                    return res.json({ satus:"success", success:"account registred succesfully" })
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
module.exports = register;
```

I think either `db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {email: email, password: password}, (error, results)=>` or `db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?' [email], async(err, result) =>` is cousing the error

`js/register.js`
here is according to the inspect page in chrome the error

```
form.addEventListener("submit", () => {
    const register = {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
    }
    fetch("/api/register", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(register),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
    }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data  => {
            if(data.status == "errpr") {
                success.style.display = "none"
                error.style.display = "block"
                error.innerText = data.error
            } else {
                error.style.display = "none"
                success.style.display = "block"
                success.innerText = data.success 
            }
        })
})
```

`routes/db-config`

```
const sql = require("mysql");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const db = sql.createConnection({
    host:process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    user:process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password:process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database:process.env.DATABASE
})

module.exports = db;
```

If more pieces of code are needed to help me solve this problem please let me know!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line

```
 db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?' [email], async(err, result) => {
```

you should put comma " , " between the query string and the list it should be

```
 db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async(err, result) => {
```